# Right displacement in spring potential energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, potential-energy, spring

[image]

I have a doubt in general, the above problem is an example.

Here , the elastic string can be treated as a spring and we know the potential energy of a spring is $\frac{1}{2} k (x_f-x_i)^2$

So , according to the problem , $x_i=a , x_f=3a \implies U=\frac{1}{2}k(3a-a)^2=2ka^2$

But apparently , this gives the wrong answer. How do i choose the correct $x_i,x_f$?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that calculation should give you the right answer - $2ka^2$ is indeed the elastic potential energy of the spring. What I suspect is going wrong is that you're not taking into account the decrease in *gravitational* potential energy that comes from the mass being pulled down. Remember, the change in gravitational energy can be expressed as $\Delta U=mg(h_f-h_i)$, which in this case is $mg(-2a)=-2amg$. Thus, if we say that the mass of the particle has $0$ potential energy at its equilibrium point, then pulling it down a distance of $2a$ leaves it with potential energy $2ka^2-2amg$, not just $2ka^2$ as you seemed to suggest. At the top of its trajectory, it will once again have $0$ kinetic energy, so you can calculate the height that it needs to be at in order for the equations to come out balanced. Try working the problem out that way, and see if it ends up getting you the correct answer!